# Count elements using std::accumulate algorithm and lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's is my problem:

I need to count the total number of elements of several std::vector contained into a std::map of type std::map>;

To count the total number of elements I use the following code:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<float>>::iterator vertex_It = myMap.begin();
uint32_t total_byte_size = 0;

for (; vertex_It != myMap.end(); ++vertex_It)
    total_byte_size += vertex_It->second.size() * sizeof(float);
```

I tried to use std::accumulate algorithm and lambda expressions like below:

```
uint32_t total_byte_size = 0;

std::accumulate(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(),
    [&total_byte_size](const uint32_t &vertex_type, const std::vector<float> &vertex_attribute) -> bool{
        total_byte_size += vertex_attribute.size();
        return (true);
});
```

But this code does not compile. I tried different combinations of code without success.

Does it exist a way to use std::accumulate and lambda expressions for this simple problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: can you give a full, not compiling, example?

Comment: are you counting the number of elements or the total size in bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways of accumulating using `std::accumulate` on a map. You could potentially shoehorn something that accumulates in a by-reference variable while returning a boolean, but a better approach is to use accumulate that computes and returns the result to you:

```
auto res = accumulate(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), (size_t)0,
    [](size_t prior, const pair<int, std::vector<float> >& p) -> size_t {
        return prior + p.second.size();
    }
);
```

Note that the third parameter is the initial value for the accumulate. Also note that the lambda is not capturing a "side" variable by reference, but gets the prior value in its first parameter. Finally note that the second parameter of lambda corresponds to what you get through map's iterators - a pair of key and value types, passed by constant reference.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/hTKyDV)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! It's an elegant way to solve this kind of problem! Bye.